# "enter into a partnership" VS "enter into partnerships"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. we have entered into **a partnership** with a host of member companies
> 2. we have entered into **partnerships** with a host of member companies.

I mean, can I use enter a partnership to express we have cooperate with each of these companes?

Which is the correct usage?

Comment: They are both correct. It depends on how many partnerships you entered into: a single one with multiple companies, or multiple ones, each with one or more companies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is correct depending on your meaning.

If you are stating accurately that you have cooperated with *each* of these companies (that would be *independently*, i.e. multiple *different* agreements with each of the companies one at a time), then you would use the plural, "partnerships".

However, if you actually mean that there was a multi-way partnership (just one relationship) among all the member companies with just *one* working agreement, then you should use the singular, "partnership".

"Partnership" is a word that is perfectly acceptable as a singular *or* a plural. But the two forms, of course, mean different things.